# Execute code in a specific date

Tags: php

Is it possible to execute a code in a spefic date?
for example : I want that when tommorow (07/01/2013) comes, a new user will be added to the database

Comment: Can you explain me how is that possible?

Comment: If you want to run the script only once at a later date have a look at `at` command.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is, but you should execute it manually.

Or use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 1):

Cron is probably the best option.

If you have a PHP application which fires frequently (e.g. a web page that loads many times a minute), you could also put your business logic in that application and hope that it fires during the window you need it to.